# ckeck if radio button is checked and show error message accordingly

Tags: php, jquery

I am not very good at programming, I try to make the following radio buttons:

```
  <input type="radio" name="yesno1" value="no" style="margin-left:30px;outline:0;"/>No</div>
          <div id="check1">*please select</div>

  <input type="radio" name="yesno2" value="yes" style="outline:0;"/>Yes
          <input type="radio" name="yesno2" value="no" style="margin-left:30px;outline:0;"/>No</div>
          <div id="check2">*please select</div>

   <input type="radio" name="yesno3" value="yes" style="outline:0;"/>Yes
          <input type="radio" name="yesno3" value="no" style="margin-left:30px;outline:0;"/>No</div>
          <div id="check3">*please select</div>

   <input type="radio" name="yesno5" value="yes" style="outline:0;"/>Yes
          <input type="radio" name="yesno5" value="no" style="margin-left:30px;outline:0;"/>No</div>
          <div id="check5">*please select</div>

     <input type="button" value="submit" id="submit">
```

here is my javascript:

```
    $("#submit").click(function(){
 if (!$("input[name='yesno1']):checked").val()) {
$("#check1").show();
   }

if ($("input[name='yesno1']):checked").val()) {
 $("#check1").hide();
    }
 if (!$("input[name='yesno2']):checked").val()) {
  $("#check2").show();
  }

if ($("input[name='yesno2']):checked").val()) {
   $("#check2").hide();
    }
if (!$("input[name='yesno3']):checked").val()) {
 $("#check3").show();
   }


 if ($("input[name='yesno3']):checked").val()) {
  $("#check3").hide();
     }
 if (!$("input[name='yesno5']):checked").val()) {
   $("#check5").show();
    }

 if ($("input[name='yesno5']):checked").val()) {
  $("#check5").hide();
     }

  });
```

I know I am doing a clumsy way, what I want is that, if only one radio button is checked, the other three error messages should show, if two is checked, the other two should show, if three check , the other one should show, if no one checked, all of them show. However only the last case works at the moment, I don't know where I am doing wrong, can any of you help me, thanks in advance.

In addition, I am going to pass the data to the php file, so is it possible if I do:

```
   $yesno1 = $_POST['yesno1'];
   $yesno2 = $_POST['yesno2'];
   $yesno3 = $_POST['yesno3'];
    $yesno5 = $_POST['yesno5'];
```

Thanks for the kind help:)

Comment: You have an extra closed paren in the selectors. Also, you can just use if-elses instead of a bunch of if-if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using jQuery `is` method. Also you can use `else` block instead of checking for `if` every time.

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
   if (!$("input[name='yesno1']").is(':checked')) {
      $("#check1").show();
   }
   else{
      $("#check1").hide();
   }

   if (!$("input[name='yesno2']").is(':checked')) {
      $("#check2").show();
   }
   else{
      $("#check2").hide();
   }

   if (!$("input[name='yesno3']").is(':checked')) {
      $("#check3").show();
   }
   else{
      $("#check3").hide();
   }

   if (!$("input[name='yesno5']").is(':checked')) {
      $("#check5").show();
   }
   else{
      $("#check5").hide();
   }

  });
```

Comment: indeed, thanks for the kind help, could you help me with the second question I stated in the end of my question about post the radio value to the php file?